# Extract link from url using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the web link of the following, using beautifulsoup

```
<div class="alignright single">
<a href="http://www.dailyhadithonline.com/2013/07/21/hadith-on-clothing-women-should-lower-their-garments-to-cover-their-feet/" rel="next">Hadith on Clothing: Women should lower their garments to cover their feet</a> &raquo;    </div>
</div>
```

My code is as follow

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                                                                                 
import urllib2                                                                                                
url1 = "http://www.dailyhadithonline.com/2013/07/21/hadith-on-clothing-the-lower-garment-should-be-hallway-between-the-shins/"

content1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content1) 

nextlink = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "alignright single"})
a = nextlink.find('a')
print a.get('href')
```

I get the following error, please help

```
a = nextlink.find('a')
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.find()` if you want to find just *one* match:

```
nextlink = soup.find("div", {"class" : "alignright single"})
```

or *loop* over all matches:

```
for nextlink in soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "alignright single"}):
    a = nextlink.find('a')
    print a.get('href')
```

The latter part can also be expressed as:

```
a = nextlink.find('a', href=True)
print a['href']
```

where the `href=True` part only matches elements that have a `href` attribute, which means that you won't have to use `a.get()` because the attribute *will* be there (alternatively, no `<a href="...">` link is found and `a` will be `None`).

For the given URL in your question, there is only one such link, so `.find()` is probably most convenient. It may even be possible to just use:

```
nextlink = soup.find('a', rel='next', href=True)
if nextlink is not None:
    print a['href']
```

with no need to find the surrounding `div`. The `rel="next"` attribute looks enough for your specific needs.

As an extra tip: make use of the response headers to tell BeautifulSoup what encoding to use for a page; the `urllib2` response object can tell you what, if any, character set the server thinks the HTML page is encoded in:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), from_encoding=response.info().getparam('charset'))
```

Quick demo of all the parts:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.dailyhadithonline.com/2013/07/21/hadith-on-clothing-the-lower-garment-should-be-hallway-between-the-shins/')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), from_encoding=response.info().getparam('charset'))
>>> soup.find('a', rel='next', href=True)['href']
u'http://www.dailyhadithonline.com/2013/07/21/hadith-on-clothing-women-should-lower-their-garments-to-cover-their-feet/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpack the list so Try this instead:

```
nextlink = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "alignright single"})[0]
```

Or since there's only one match the `find` method also ought to work:

```
nextlink = soup.find("div", {"class" : "alignright single"})
```